# How can I encrypt .docx files with AES & pycrypto without corrupting the files

Tags: python, aes, pycrypto

I've got this bit of python code that I want to use to encrypt various kinds of files with AES 256. I am using the pycrypto module. It works fine for most files (exe, deb, jpg, pdf, txt) but when it comes to office files (docx, xlsx, ppt etc) the file is corrupted upon decryption and will no open (nor can it be repaired) in LibreOffice. I am using Linux mint, python 2.7.6, pycrypto 2.6.1. I'm still a bit of a noob so I'd appreciate it if you could give me code examples of the corrections you'd recommend.

Thanks

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import os

def pad(s):
    return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

def encrypt(message, key, key_size=256):
    message = pad(message)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)

def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:])
    return plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")

def encrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        plaintext = fo.read()
    enc = encrypt(plaintext, key)
    with open(file_name + ".enc", 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(enc)

def decrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        ciphertext = fo.read()
    dec = decrypt(ciphertext, key)
    with open(file_name[:-4], 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(dec)

key = b'\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x94\x02)j\xdf\xcb\xc4\x94\x9d(\x9e[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\xd5\x18'

encrypt_file('file.docx', key)
```

Comment: Playing around with it myself, it looks like it has something to do with those trailing zeros getting stripped. In the one I tried, those zeros were the only difference between the input and output binaries (that I could see at a glance). Oddly enough though, if I remove the `.rstrip(b"\0")`, then it puts in *too many* zeros. I think this has to do with the output being a multiple of 16? I'm not sure.

Comment: Try converting the document to b64 first and encrypt that. That should preserve the structure of the document but it is, admittedly, somewhat wasteful.

Comment: @user3681638 You can find an example in [this](https://github.com/nafscript/cnox) simple tool. Tested with .docx

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here

```
plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")
```

I have run the program and see the reason is:

> There was a bug in here that caused the last bytes of the original file to be discarded if they happened to have the same value as the padding bytes!

To fix this issue, we have to store how many padding bytes were used during encryption, then remove them during decryption. Here is my code, it works for me (tested with word and excel 2013 files, pdf, jpg). Let me know if still some bugs.

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

import hashlib

def pad(s):
    padding_size = AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size
    return s + b"\0" * padding_size, padding_size

def encrypt(message, key, key_size=256):
    message, padding_size = pad(message)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    enc_bytes = iv + cipher.encrypt(message) + bytes([padding_size])    
    return enc_bytes

def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:-1])
    padding_size = ciphertext[-1] * (-1)
    return plaintext[:padding_size]

def encrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        plaintext = fo.read()    
    enc = encrypt(plaintext, key)
    with open(file_name + ".enc", 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(enc)

def decrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        ciphertext = fo.read()
    dec = decrypt(ciphertext, key)
    with open('processed_' + file_name[:-4], 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(dec)

key = 'Quan'
hash_object = hashlib.md5(key.encode())

while True:
    filename = input('File: ')
    en_de = input('En or De?')
    if en_de.upper() == 'EN':
        encrypt_file(filename, hash_object.hexdigest())
    elif en_de.upper() == 'DE':
        decrypt_file(filename, hash_object.hexdigest())
    else:
        print('Did not pick either en or de!')

    cont = input('Continue?')
    if cont.upper() == 'N':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add padding to make the plaintext a multiple of 16 bytes, the extra bytes need to be stripped before you write the decrypted data. This means you will need to somehow include the number of pad bytes added with the padding before you encrypt it. See PKCS#7 for one possible technique. There are a number of other schemes as well.